# Can a .DER be converted to a .PFX / .P12 ?

Tags: tls, openssl, proxy, sniffer, burp-suite

***Burp-Suite***'s *`http://burp/cert:8080`* ***web-interface*** for downloading the ***CA Certificate*** only provides a *`.der`* encoded certificate, but for a particular use-case scenario I require a ***PKCS#12*** *`.pfx`/`.p12`.*

I can find a lot of information regarding the conversion from *`.der` to `.pem`* and also the conversion from *`.pem` to `.pfx`/`.p12`,* but nothing for converting directly from *`.der` to `.pfx`/`.p12`:*

---

- ***`.der` > `.pem`***

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.der -out certificate.pem
```

---

- ***`.pem` > `.pfx`/`.p12`***

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.pem -out certificate.p12
```

---

1. Can I convert directly from *`.der` to `.pfx`/`.p12`*?
2. Do I need a *`.key`* *(not provided via `http://burp/cert:8080`)* in order to do the conversion?
3. Will the *`.pfx`/`.p12`* even be of any use to me *(and **Burp-Suite**)* without the *`.key`* rolled in?

Comment: commandline `openssl pkcs12` cannot create a p12 without a privatekey (with matching cert). If your 'particular use-case' is Burp, it intercepts HTTPS by using CAkey to forge certs so the CAcert alone is useless. I don't know any software that uses a p12 with only cert(s) except Java 8, and for Java JKS has better support for either privatekey&chain OR certs-only. But you can use Java 8 `keytool` to 'import' lone cert(s), either DER or PEM, to a p12.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Can I convert directly from a `.der` to a `.pfx`/`.p12`?

I don't think so because Openssl uses `PEM` encoding for certificates by default unless you set it explicitly using `-inform` or `-outform` arguments. There is no such option listed in the [pkcs12](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/pkcs12.html) command.

> 2. Do I need a `.key` (not provided via `http://burp/cert:8080`) in order to do the conversion?

You don't have to provide a key for PKCS12 command if you use `-nodes` option. With this option openssl do not use encryption for the file created.

> 3. Will the `.pfx`/`.p12` even be of any use to me (and *Burp-Suite*) without the `.key` rolled in?

In your case, Yes. Because that you will only store your certificates in that file you do not need it to be encrypted. Note that, PKCS12 file format is generally used to store private keys with their corresponding certificates in a single file format. In that case, you should use a key to keep your private keys in an encrypted file.

Comment: `openssl pkcs12 -nodes` applies only when _reading_ a p12 and extracting to separate key&cert (PEM) files; it is ignored when _writing_ a p12. Although openssl library can create a p12 with only cert(s), commandline `pkcs12` cannot. And in openssl by defaul, and other software I've looked at (Microsoft, Mozilla, and Java) _always_, certs _are_ encrypted, although weakly so (commonly pbeSHA1wirthRC2-40).